# remove item in list based on item of other list

Tags: c#, list

How do I remove items from one list based on items in other list?

Basically I want to compare list1 and list2 and the the difference each item in these lists should removed.

ex: I have a class call Dog

```
class Dog
{
   private string _name;
    public string Name
        {
            get { return selisih; }
            set { selisih = value; }
        }

}
```

in winform

```
list<Dog> Dog1 = new list<Dog>();
list<Dog> Dog2 = new list<Dog>();
```

and add items to this list. How should I do to compare these two lists? and when items in Dog1 did not exist in Dog2. Those items should be deleted or removed from Dog1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use LINQ - the [`Except`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb356791.aspx) method should do.

```
var dog3 = Dog1.Except(Dog2).ToList();
```

You will probably need to pass in a function that compares dogs, so it knows how to do this.

Untested:

```
var dog3 = Dog1.Except(Dog2, (d1, d2) => d1.Name.CompareTo(d2.Name)).ToList();
```

Comment: It's all not very clear, but to me *"and when items in Dog1 did not exist in Dog2. Those items should be deleted or removed from Dog1."* means `Intersect` not `Except`.

Comment: @BrokenGlass - I am looking before his examples: _"and the the difference each item in these lists should removed"_, which to me means Except ;)

Comment: Ah well - I guess you are right you could see it that way too ;-) +1 for taking the time to argue your solution, let me remove all my other comments.

Answer (score 2):

you can do it in LINQ like

```
Dog1.ForEach(x => 
            {
                if (!Dog2.Select(z=>z.Name).Contains(x.Name)) 
                {
                    Dog1.Remove(x);
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet would be to loop over the list you need to synchronize using [List.Contains()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bhkz42b3.aspx) to check if the item exists.

For example:

```
For Each Dog As Dog In Dog1
If Dog2.Contains(Dog) = False Then
Dog2.Add(Dog)
End If
End For
```

To add items that don't exist in the second list, but do in the first.

Comment: As a note, if you're instantiating different dogs, and you're just checking to see if both Dog1 and Dog2 have, for instance, a greyhound, you'll want to implement some form of equality comparison (IComparable or such) to your Dog class.  List.Contains() would otherwise only work if you're actually adding the same instances of Dog to both lists.